# Getting count of display none elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden

```
     var checkLeft= $('#left .module:hidden');
     if(checkLeft) {
        if($('.resetLeft').length) {
          left.prepend('<span class="resetLeft">Reset Left Widgets</span>');
         }
     }
```

Having a bit of trouble trying to get this to work properly. As I really don't want the `:hidden` pseudo-class as I believe IE doesn't support this. Basically I  made a function and this code is in it. And when it runs it checks if the parent element `#left` has any `display:none` children of class `.module` I have used the filter function, and had to have two elements hidden to actually respond correctly. Any good ideas on this?

here is a started JSBIN

http://jsbin.com/upuwix/1/edit

Comment: _as I believe IE doesn't support this._ That's not true, jQuery  supports it.

Comment: Ok thank you undefined, I thought it wasn't supported. Does IE7 8 9 and support? Only reason I question is because XP users can't go to IE9 or 10. (Atleast the guy who uses XP told me this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Part of) the point of jQuery is that it works cross-browser. [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) works as a jQuery selector in all browsers - the [doco](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) says it "is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification".

However, your `if` test is incorrect:

```
if(checkLeft) {
```

...will always be true because you are testing the jQuery object itself - objects are always truthy. You need to test the `.length` to see if any elements matched your selector:

```
if (checkLeft.length) {
```

On the line after that one you were already using this same technique:

```
   if($('.resetLeft').length) {
```

...except on that line you have the logic backwards - you want it to be true if the length is 0, i.e., if there are no `.resetLeft` elements yet, so either add `!` at the beginning of the condition or test for `.length === 0`:

```
   if(!$('.resetLeft').length) {
```

Finally, `left.prepend(...)` didn't work because you have no `left` variable. Either define it or use `$('#left').prepend(...)`.

Updated demo: http://jsbin.com/upuwix/3/edit

Comment: Yes I realized this after a moment lol. Just a wee bit tired. I did do length on the test site.  thanks though ;) just worried on the :hidden I will read the doc link you provided

Comment: My bad on the left part, I do have it defined, I just never added that from my code :X

Comment: _"I will read the doc link you provided"_ - Cool. May I suggest that next time you read the doco _before_ posting a question, and don't leave variable definitions out of code you post? If `:hidden` is really the only part you had a problem with then there is no problem.

Comment: Yeah no problem any more ;) And yes I will, I was looking for it on google and could not find it one bit. See I thought it was only a CSS pseudo and not a extension of jQuery. And again sorry for leaving that out ;)

Comment: Cool. There are some other CSS pseudo classes that are not supported in all browsers in a general sense but which jQuery supports in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn I appreciate it, I may need help with a cookie code :D